# How do I add custom variables to Material Ui Theme?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm building a react app in typescript and using Material Ui. I'm trying to create some custom types to my themes but I get the following error:

`TS2322: Type '{ mode: "dark"; background: { default: string; paper: string; }; text: { primary: string; secondary: string; }; primary: { main: string; light: string; dark: string; contrastText: string; }; success: { main: string; light: string; dark: "#43a047"; contrastText: string; }; ... 5 more ...; divider: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'customYellow' does not exist in type 'PaletteOptions'."`

This is my code:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { green, red, yellow, orange } from "@mui/material/colors";
import components from "./components";
import typography from "./typography";

//dark and light themes
export default {
    dark: createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: "dark",
            background: {
                default: "rgb(21, 22, 43)",
                paper: "rgb(35, 48, 68)"
            },
            text: {
                primary: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)",
                secondary: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
            },
            ...
            info: {
                main: 'rgb(142, 221, 229)',
                light: 'rgb(183, 238, 242)',
                dark: 'rgb(92, 205, 219',
                contrastText: 'rgb(235, 234, 239)',
            },
            customYellow: {
                dark: yellow[800],
                main: 'rgb(250, 222, 101)',
                light: 'rgb(252, 237, 133)',
            },
            customTable: {
                dark: "rgb(21, 28, 38)",
                light: "rgb(30, 32, 36)"
            },
            divider: 'rgb(85, 89, 110)',
        },
        typography: typography,
        components: components
    }),
};
```

How can I use augment the module to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use module augmentation to add new variables to the Palette and PaletteOptions.

[doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/)